# Net::Telnet eof read waiting for login prompt: at test.pl line 25

Tags: perl

My code is given below for reference

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::Telnet::Cisco;
my ($host, $port, $user, $pass, $command);

##### get host info
print 'Enter host: ';
chop($host = <STDIN>);
##### get port info
print 'Enter port: ';
chop($port = <STDIN>);
##### get user info
print 'Enter user: ';
chop($user = <STDIN>);
##### get user info & hide input
print 'Enter password: ';
system 'stty -echo';
chop($pass = <STDIN>);
system 'stty echo';
print "\n";

my $tn = new Net::Telnet(Host =>$host, Port =>$port, Timeout => 20)
 or die "connect failed: $!";
$tn->open ($host);
$tn->login('','L@ser123');
$tn->login('$user','$pass');
my @out1 = $tn->print("sh run");
print "@out1\n";
```

Am trying to login through terminal server console port and execute command but facing "eof read waiting for login prompt: at test.pl line 25" Error.
Any help would be appreciated,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the first `->login` method waits for a prompt before returning. But when running telnet through a terminal server (TS), you will never get a normal prompt on the TS, it will pass you directly to the device on the console port.

If you would like to stay with the current configuration of the TS, you probably must something clever using `->waitfor`, a sometimes confusing task.

What I recommend you to do is reconfigure the TS not to authenticate telnet "pass-throughs", after all it's the device connected to the TS which must be protected with a usrname/password combo. As you are using `Net::Telnet::Cisco` I assume the TS is a Cisco-device. Here is the config we are using for our (very old) 2511 TSes, but the concept applies to newer Ciscos as well:

```
aaa new-model
!
! normal authentication scheme (named 'default') for connections terminating
! ON THE TERMINAL SERVER (here via tacacs+)
aaa authentication login default tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default tacacs+ enable
!
! create an authentication scheme (named 'line_auth') with no authentication
aaa authentication login line_auth none

line 1 16
 ! disable access to the TS from the serial line side, i.e only allow
 ! *outgoing* connections
 no exec
 !
 ! use the 'line_auth' authentication scheme, i.e no authentication
 login authentication line_auth
 !
 ! only allow telnet connections to connect to the line
 transport input telnet
!
line vty 0 4
 ! default authentication scheme (this is a default config, so it's
 ! actually not shown in the config).
 login authentication default
!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to login twice:

```
$tn->login('','L@ser123');
$tn->login('$user','$pass');
```

The second time, the login prompt will already be gone and it will time out waiting for it. Remove one of these lines.

Comment: i removed 1st line but also same error am facing the same error , i removed enable password to ma switch, so now i can directly login to privilege mode the pattern as fallows SW-SANT-TEST1-T15#

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you should only be using `login()` if the device asks for a password. If you log in directly without credentials, you can remove both of these lines.

Comment: @out1 = $tn->print("sh run") i just replaced cmd in place of print, but getting error pattern match read eof at test4diff.pl.save line